# counting number of empty inputs with a certain class

Tags: jquery, count

I have tried a couple of solutions from previous questions, but no luck. Hoping someone can help me out.

I have a section of a form where fields are dynamically created with a certain class:

```
 <td><input class="user_field" type="text" name="1[user_fname]"/></td>
 <td><input class="user_field" type="text" name="1[user_lname]"/></td>
 <td><input class="user_field phone" type="text" name="1[user_mobile]"/></td>
 <td><input class="user_field" type="text" name="1[user_email]"/></td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
```

On blur i need to check for empties and have tried:

```
$('.user_field').blur(function(){

    //check all fields for complete

    alert ($('.user_field[value=""]').length)

});
```

and get "0"

Comment: Why not use `.user_field` and check the length of all fields with `.each()`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will give you all empty inputs:

```
$('.user_field').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).val();
}).length;
```

Comment: You should add a `.length` after the filter to return the count.

Comment: Thank you elclanrs!! This works. I assigned it to a variable so that i could put it inside an if statement

Comment: Thank you brother!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.user_field').blur(function(){
    alert ($('.user_field').filter('[value=""]').length);
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nD4U2/1/)***

Answer (score 2):

mm just posting my version using `.not`

```
$('.user_field').blur(function() {
   var count = $('.user_field').not(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).length;

    alert(count);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jMEdx/1/)**