# counting number input filed with jquery 1.9+

Tags: jquery, validation

I have inherited someone else's jquery to count how many form boxes have been completed, can be a mix of check boxes text.
Now this worked but it seems since jquery1.9 there is a change to this function.

```
<input type="text" name="company" placeholder="" class="required" />
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="" class="required" />
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com" class="required" />
```

The offending jquery which fails is this:

```
var sel=".required"
var filled = $(sel + "[value!='']").not(':checkbox, :radio').length + $(sel + ':checked').length;
```

from what I can gather from jquery v1.9+ the value now needs to be like ($.trim($(sel).val()
but I just am not able to work out  the exact string.

this is the found example I already checked. 
[counting number of empty inputs with a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486716/counting-number-of-empty-inputs-with-a-certain-class)
when I change the jquery on these answers they also fail with 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
var filled = $(sel).not(':checkbox, :radio').filter(function() {
    return this.value != '';
}).length + $(sel + ':checked').length;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xAYaf/4/)

Comment: Hi Barmar, this worked perfectly. Very much appreciated.